# É possível adicionar uma function em um json?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-datatables

Vamos ao problema.
No datatable.js, para exibir as colunas eu defino da seguinte maneira:

```
    "aoColumns": [
                { "mDataProp": "IdProcesso", "sTitle": "Numero" }
                 ]
```

Caso necessite executar alguma função:

```
                 {
                    "mDataProp": "DataAbertura", "sTitle": "Data Abertura",
                    "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                        return //minha function vem aqui!
                    }
                },
```

Agora vem a dúvida é possível eu adicionar essa function no objeto Json de maneira dinâmica?
Quando eu digo dinâmico me refiro ao fato que esse objeto será criado por outra function e ao final ele me retorna uma string gerada pelo JSON.stringify e a function fica inutilizada.
Espero que eu tenha conseguido explicar minha dúvida

Comment: Em um json não mas num objeto sim, se o datatable usa ou não é outra questão :) Esse objeto vai ser serializado em json ou é para ser consumido pela API datatable?

Comment: A aplicação já recebe um json eu queria adicionar a função. Então jeito vai ser criar o objeto e adicionar a função necessária. Ok, valeu mesmo pela ajuda.

Comment: Esse objeto vai ser serializado em json ou é para ser consumido pela API datatable?

Comment: Consumido pela API.

Comment: @DeividsonOliveira, não sei se ainda é relevante... mas você pode passar a sua function como uma string e ao criar o objeto construí-la de fato utilizando a classe Function(). Porém, isso passa longe de uma boa prática...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há uma alternativa, utilizando a função `eval`

A função `eval` executa a `string` passada a ela, como você pode ver no exemplo abaixo:

https://jsfiddle.net/yrzruztw/

```
eval('alert("teste")');
```

Isso fará o alert aparecer na tela. Portanto minha sugestão é que você salve sua função no formato de `string`, e a execute assim.